# How to organize package/modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

My life with python is just started. I am clueless about how to organize folders in python(flask)

My intention is to organize my application in following directory/file structure

src[image]

`server.py` is the main file

`database.py` holding DB related sharable resources

`customer.py` is a simple python class which need DB instance from `database.py`

```
from ....shared.database import DB # How to solve this

class Customer():
    def __init__(self):
        self._first_name="John"
```

but I am getting an error `Attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

How do I make this works?!.

folder strucure representation

```
src
  app
    /modules
         /customers
              /models
                 customer.py
    /shared
       /database.py
  /server.py
```

Comment: There are loads of tutorials online, SO isn’t the best place for this question.  Perhaps [start here](https://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html).  Regarding relative imports, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72852/6340496).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Your directories need to contain an `__init__.py` file in order to be recognized as packages and thus work with imports. The file can be empty.

More info on `__init__.py` here: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Answer (score 0):

To declare your folder as the package you should add blank **init**.py files in each folder which contains any code that you want to call from other subfolders.

And if you are still not able to do it then, please see this other alternative.

You can try doing this as a quick way to access other source codes from other subfolders within the same module:
Add this before doing your import
if **name** == '**main**':
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
from app.shared.database import DB